# How to Stop So Many Bubble Ups of Events in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

due to certain factors(SalesForce) I am looking of only using reactjs and not something like redux.

I going to have something like this

```
 <script type="text/babel">

class Main extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
                items : [
                            {
                                year: 2016,
                            },
                            {
                                year: '',
                            },
                          ]
                };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
      }
      handleChange(event, index){
         let items = this.state.items;
         let item = items[index];

         item[event.target.name] = event.target.value;

         items[index] = item;
         this.setState({ items: items});
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <div className="main"> 
                {
                      this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
                          return <Item item={item} index={i}  handleChange={(event,index) => this.handleChange(event,index)}  />
                      })
                }
              </div>
          )
      }
    }

class Item extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
      }
      componentDidMount() {
      }
      handleChange(event){
         this.props.handleChange(event, this.props.index);
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <div className="item"> 
                    <Sub item={this.props.item} index={this.props.index}  handleChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} />
              </div>
          )
      }
    }

  class Sub extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
      }
      componentDidMount() {
      }
      handleChange(event) {
        this.props.handleChange(event, this.props.index);
      } 
      render() {
          return (
              <div className="container"> 
                  <div>
                    <label>Year </label>
                    <input type="text" name="year" value={asset.year} className={year} onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}/>
                  </div>
              </div>
          )
      }
    }



  ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("Container"));
 </script>
```

I am wondering is there away so that when someone types something in "year" in sub component I don't have to have handleChange that goes up to the Item handleChange and finally to the Main handleChange.

Comment: Like I said, I would like to use them but putting Redux is not the easiest thing to do in Salesforce. So trying to see if I can do something without using those.

Comment: How about custom event (listeners)?

Comment: Can you go into that more detail?